# Field countRepo in com.abc.serive.MysqlService required a bean of type 'com.abc.repository.ClicksQuickReplyRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot

```
package com.abc.repository.ClicksQuickReplyRepository;

import com.abc.model.ClicksQuickReply;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ClicksQuickReplyRepository{

    @Query( value = "select notificationTag,count,button_id from fb_sent_messages where page_id=?1 and notificationTag in ?2", nativeQuery=true)
    List<ClicksQuickReply> getClickCount(@Param("pageID") String pageID, @Param("notificationTag")  String notificationTag);
}
```

MySQL Service Class

```
package com.abc.serive.MysqlService;

@Service
public class MysqlService {

@Autowired
    private ClicksQuickReplyRepository clicksQuickReplyRepository;

}
```

Autowiring the ClicksQuickReplyRepository results in error:

```
Field clicksQuickReplyRepository in com.abc.serive.MysqlService required a bean of type 'com.abc.repository.ClicksQuickReplyRepository' that could not be found.
```

I have tried following in attempt to fix it:

1. Add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to SpringConfiguration class
2. Added `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.abc.repository"})`
   i.e `scanBasePackage` // starts resulting in same error for other packages

Comment: In what package is the `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: com.abc package    @Andronicus

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by wrong mapping, in your query there is `where page_id=?1` whereas your parameter's name is `pageID`. Those should be equal. Wrong mapping causes no bean to inject.

Comment: I changed it per your suggestion:
    @Query( value = "select notificationTag,count,button_id from fb_sent_messages where page_id=?1 and notificationTag in ?2", nativeQuery=true)
    List<ClicksQuickReply> getClickCount(@Param("page_id") String page_id, @Param("notificationTag")  String notificationTag);

Comment: are you sure, those are valid column names? one is camelCase, the other with `_`

Comment: Yes, have cross checked that as well